# Warning: The tag <> is unrecognized in this browser. If you meant to render a React component, start its name with an uppercase letter

Tags: reactjs, svg, jestjs

When running tests with jest in a React project with TypeScript, I run into the following error:

```
Warning: The tag <g> is unrecognized in this browser. If you meant to render a React component, start its name with an uppercase letter.
```

Or this error:

```
Warning: The tag <circle> is unrecognized in this browser. If you meant to render a React component, start its name with an uppercase letter.
```

I tried using [`jest-svg-transformer`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-svg-transformer) to allow jest to understand SVG, but this didn't work since this package (and all its forks) don't work with jest v29+.

It turns out, this is a whole other issue. And the fix is simple (Read answer).

Answer (score 1):

The error in my case stems from the fact that I use a `CustomComponent` that looks something like this:

```
export default function CustomComponent(props) {
  return (
    <g>
      <circle {...props} />
    </g>
  );
}
```

There is no `<svg>` that wraps the `<g>` element as would be required for svg.

There is a good reason to leave it out, as the `CustomComponent` is used in a library component and is required to leave out the  tag.

The fix is to wrap the `CustomComponent` in the test file like this:

```
it('should test something', () => {
    const { baseElement } = render(
      <svg>
        <CustomDot
          {...props}
        />
      </svg>,
    );
    ...
});
```

Of course, if you don't need to leave out the  tag in the CustomComponent, you can just wrap the svg elements in the component itself instead of in the test file.